# drupal 7 how to display comments of a node in popup using views?

Tags: php, drupal-7, popup, comments, view

1. created a view of type comments.
2. added required fields like Content: Nid,Global: Popup,Content: Comment count
3. added filters like Content: Published (Yes),Content: Type (= xxxxxx)
4. added relationship like Comment: Comments of the node.
5. I am displaying comment count and on clicking it a popup will display showing list of comments on that node.
6. I could get single comment in popup where i need all comments.
7. for example:if i got 3 comments for a node the node is rendering 3 times displaying single comment in each node.
8. can any one help me to get display all comments in single node.[image: i have two comments for SAT-107 which are displaying individually i need them together in single popup]